# Data Integration Structure using Python and/or SSIS

Tags: python, database, database-design, ssis

I have a question on the general strategy of how to integrate data into an MSSQL database.

Currently, I use python for my whole ETL process.  I use it to clean, transform, and integrate the data in an MSSQL database.  My data is small so I think this process works fine for now.

However, I think it a little awkward for my code to constantly read data and write data to the database.  I think this strategy will be an issue once I'm dealing with large amount of data and the constant read/write seems very inefficient.  However, I don't know enough to know if this is a real problem or not.

I want to know if this is a feasible approach or should I switch entirely to SSIS to handle it.  SSIS to me is clunky and I'd prefer not to re-write my entire code.  Any input on the general ETL architecture would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you help explain what you mean by `I think it a little awkward for my code to constantly read data and write data to the database`

Comment: Apologies.  My current set-up is that my current python code reads the data from an mssql database.  It performs the cleaning and the transformation then writes the data back into the mssql database.  Is this practice alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is this practice alright?` *Maybe*?
There are too many factors to give a definitive answer. Conceptually, what you're doing - Extract data from source, Transform it, Load it to destination, ETL, is all that SSIS does. It likely can do things more efficiently than python - at least I've had a devil of a time getting a bulk load to work with memory mapped data. Dump to disk and bulk insert that via python - no problem. But, if the existing process works, then let it go until it doesn't work.

If your team knows Python, introducing SSIS just to do ETL is likely going to be a bigger maintenance cost than scaling up your existing approach. On the other hand, if it's standard-ish Python + libraries and you're on [SQL Server 2017+](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/04/19/python-in-sql-server-2017-enhanced-in-database-machine-learning/), you might be able to execute your scripts from within the database itself via [sp_execute_external_script](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/)

If the ETL process runs on the same box as the database, then ensure you have sufficient resources to support both processes at their maximum observed levels of activity. If the ETL runs elsewhere, then you'll want to ensure you have fast, full duplex connectivity between the database server and the processing box.

Stand up a load testing environment that parallels production's resources. Dummy up a 10x increase in source data and observe how the ETL fares. 100x, 1000x. At some point, you'll identify what development sins you committed that do not scale and *then* you're poised to ask a really good, detailed question describing the current architecture, the specific code that does not perform well under load and how one can reproduce this load.

The above design considerations will hold true for Python, SSIS or any other ETL solution - prepackaged or bespoke.

Comment: No worries.  I do understand my question was broad.  Thank you for the strategy of assessment that I will need to do in order to find the best solution.  cheers.